# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection during processing local report

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I get the following exception

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

when calling this method :

```
private void AddReportToResponse(LocalReport Report)
{
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string extension;
    string[] streams = new string[100];
    Warning[] warnings = new Warning[100];
    byte[] pdfStream = Report.Render("PDF", "", out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streams, out warnings);//The error here
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = mimeType;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Application." + extension);
    Response.BinaryWrite(pdfStream);
    Response.End();
}
```

The stack trace :

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
   System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) +7487176
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.MatrixCellCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +36
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.MatrixCellGrid.get_Item(Int32 column, Int32 row) +109
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.Matrix.ResizeCellsHorizontally(ReAdjustments& itemReAdjustment, Double& rowHeadersWidth, Int32& firstRowOnPage, Int32& firstRowHeadersCol, Int32& lastRowHeadersCol, Double& newChildrenMaximumDistance) +293
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.Matrix.CalculateItemMeasurement(Orientation orientation, Double childrenMaximumDistance, ReAdjustments itemReAdjustment, ItemContext savedContext) +1611
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RenderingItemContainer.CalculatePage(Orientation orientation, Boolean repeatableParent, Boolean canDelete, Double& minimumCoordinate, Double& distance) +3566
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RenderingItemContainer.CalculatePage(Orientation orientation, Boolean repeatableParent, Boolean canDelete, Double& minimumCoordinate, Double& distance) +2717
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RenderingItemContainer.CalculatePage(Orientation orientation, Boolean repeatableParent, Boolean canDelete, Double& minimumCoordinate, Double& distance) +2717
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RenderingItemContainer.CalculatePage(Orientation orientation, Boolean repeatableParent, Boolean canDelete, Double& minimumCoordinate, Double& distance) +2717
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RenderingItemContainer.CalculatePage(Orientation orientation, Boolean repeatableParent, Boolean canDelete, Double& minimumCoordinate, Double& distance) +2717
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.ImageRendererBase.ProcessPages(CompositionBase theComposition, Report theReport, Boolean needTotalPages, Int32 startPage, Int32 endPage, Boolean render) +325
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PdfReport.RenderReport(Report report, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, EvaluateHeaderFooterExpressions evaluateHeaderFooterExpressions, CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStreamCallback, Int32 streamPageNumber) +324
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.ImageRendererBase.Render(Report report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection clientCapabilities, EvaluateHeaderFooterExpressions evaluateHeaderFooterExpressions, CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream) +81

[ReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report.]
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.ImageRendererBase.Render(Report report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection clientCapabilities, EvaluateHeaderFooterExpressions evaluateHeaderFooterExpressions, CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream) +142
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.RenderReport(IRenderingExtension renderer, DateTime executionTimeStamp, GetReportChunk getCompiledDefinitionCallback, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, CreateReportChunk cacheDataCallback, Boolean& dataCached) +1775
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and debugging, I found the cause of the problem:

I used `matrix` in my report and maybe rendering improperly, so I just tried to set the data source for this matrix as empty data table and it works fine. So I know where's the problem is, and after some (tweaks) for the height and the width of the matrix every thing is okay:

[image]